# SVG does not open properly in vector editors or convert properly using ImageMagick

Tags: svg, png, imagemagick-convert

I've been mightily struggling with being able to properly size and scale an svg image in a web page and have it flow properly. I've decided to give up and convert it to a png.

```html
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   width="1920" height="165px"
   viewBox="0 0 1920 165"
   >

  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter');
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed');
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab');
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov|Vollkorn');
    </style>
    <style>
      :root {
      --graphics: #670309;
      --logo-text: #282B28;
      --services: #fff;
      --bottom-bar-font-size: 0.8em;
      }
      .house{
        fill: none;
        stroke: var(--graphics);
      }
      .bottom{
        fill: var(--graphics);
        stroke: none;
      }
      .logo{
        fill: var(--logo-text);
        stroke: none;
      }
      .features{
        fill: #282B28;
        stroke: none;
      }

      .services {
          fill: var(--services);
          stroke: none;
          text-anchor: start;
          alignment-baseline="middle"
          font-weight="400"
          font-family="Roboto Condensed"
          letter-spacing="0.03em"
      }

      .service {
        font-size: var(--bottom-bar-font-size);
        font-family="Roboto Condensed";
      }

      .separator {
        font-size: var(--bottom-bar-font-size);
        font-family="Roboto Condensed";
      }
    </style>
  </defs>

  <g id="whole-logo" transform="translate(0,0)scale(1)">
    <svg>
      <!--  ROOF  -->
      <path d="m 5 100 l 90 -50 l 90 50" stroke-width="15" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" class="house"/>

      <!--  CHIMNEY  -->
      <path d="m 155 60 l 0 20" stroke-width="15" stroke-linecap="butt" class="house"/>

      <!--  LEFT WALL -->
      <path d="m 25 90 l 0 60" stroke-width="12" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" class="house"/>

      <!--  RIGHT WALL -->
      <path d="m 165 90 l 0 60" stroke-width="12" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" class="house"/>

      <!--  DOOR  -->
      <rect x="60" y="95" height="45" width="25" class="features"/>

      <!--  SINGLE WINDOW DEFINITION -->
      <defs>
        <rect id="window" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" class="features"/>
      </defs>

      <!--  WINDOWS  -->
      <g transform="translate(105,95)">
        <use href="#window" transform="translate(0 0)"/>
        <use href="#window" transform="translate(0 12)"/>
        <use href="#window" transform="translate(12 0)"/>
        <use href="#window" transform="translate(12 12)"/>
      </g>

      <!--  BOTTOM BAR AND TEXT -->
      <g transform="translate(0,140)">
        <svg width="100%" height="25px">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="25px" class="bottom" stroke-width="0"/>
          <text x="1.5em" y="65%" class="services" font-family="Roboto Condensed" >
            <tspan class="service">residential</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">commercial</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">pre-purchase</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">pre-sale</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">warranty</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">expert-witness</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">sewer</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">radon</tspan>
          </text>

        </svg>
      </g>

      <!--  HOUSE DETECTIVES LLC  -->
      <g id="biz-name" transform="translate(265,140)scale(0.8)">
        <line x1="0" x2="500" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: green"></line>
        <text dx="70px" dy="0"
          text-anchor="start"
          font-size="38px"
          font-family="Roboto Slab"
          font-weight="bold"
          transform="rotate(-90)"
          class="logo">the</text>
        <text dx="0" dy="0"
          text-anchor="start"
          font-size="78px"
          font-family="Roboto Slab"
          font-weight="bold"
          class="logo">
            <tspan class="name" x="5" dx="0" dy="-73">House</tspan>
            <tspan class="name" x="-70" dx="0" dy="65">Detectives</tspan>
            <tspan class="name" x="0" dx="330" dy="-2" font-size="24px">llc</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </g>
</svg>
```

My svg renders just fine in a browser, and I've validated it with [validator.nu](https://validator.nu/). However, it does not open properly in any vector editor I've tried including Inkscape and others. For instance, Inkscape looks like:

[image]

It also does not convert properly with ImageMagick.

[image]

I get pretty close with [drawsvg.org](http://www.drawsvg.org/drawsvg.html)

[image]

What should I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Percentage values are not valid in `viewBox` attributes.  The purpose of the `viewBox` attribute is to tell the browser the dimensions of the bounding box around the content in the SVG.

In the case of your SVG a suitabel `viewBox` would be:

```
viewBox="0 0 620 165"
```

```html
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   width="100%" height="165px"
   viewBox="0 0 620 165"
   >

  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter');
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed');
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab');
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov|Vollkorn');
    </style>
    <style>
      :root {
      --graphics: #670309;
      --logo-text: #282B28;
      --services: #fff;
      --bottom-bar-font-size: 0.8em;
      }
      .house{
        fill: none;
        stroke: var(--graphics);
      }
      .bottom{
        fill: var(--graphics);
        stroke: none;
      }
      .logo{
        fill: var(--logo-text);
        stroke: none;
      }
      .features{
        fill: #282B28;
        stroke: none;
      }

      .services {
          fill: var(--services);
          stroke: none;
          text-anchor: start;
          alignment-baseline="middle"
          font-weight="400"
          font-family="Roboto Condensed"
          letter-spacing="0.03em"
      }

      .service {
        font-size: var(--bottom-bar-font-size);
        font-family="Roboto Condensed";
      }

      .separator {
        font-size: var(--bottom-bar-font-size);
        font-family="Roboto Condensed";
      }
    </style>
  </defs>

  <g id="whole-logo" transform="translate(0,0)scale(1)">
    <svg>
      <!--  ROOF  -->
      <path d="m 5 100 l 90 -50 l 90 50" stroke-width="15" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" class="house"/>

      <!--  CHIMNEY  -->
      <path d="m 155 60 l 0 20" stroke-width="15" stroke-linecap="butt" class="house"/>

      <!--  LEFT WALL -->
      <path d="m 25 90 l 0 60" stroke-width="12" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" class="house"/>

      <!--  RIGHT WALL -->
      <path d="m 165 90 l 0 60" stroke-width="12" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" class="house"/>

      <!--  DOOR  -->
      <rect x="60" y="95" height="45" width="25" class="features"/>

      <!--  SINGLE WINDOW DEFINITION -->
      <defs>
        <rect id="window" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" class="features"/>
      </defs>

      <!--  WINDOWS  -->
      <g transform="translate(105,95)">
        <use href="#window" transform="translate(0 0)"/>
        <use href="#window" transform="translate(0 12)"/>
        <use href="#window" transform="translate(12 0)"/>
        <use href="#window" transform="translate(12 12)"/>
      </g>

      <!--  BOTTOM BAR AND TEXT -->
      <g transform="translate(0,140)">
        <svg width="100%" height="25px">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="25px" class="bottom" stroke-width="0"/>
          <text x="1.5em" y="65%" class="services" font-family="Roboto Condensed" >
            <tspan class="service">residential</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">commercial</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">pre-purchase</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">pre-sale</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">warranty</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">expert-witness</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">sewer</tspan>
            <tspan class="separator" dx="5px">&#9632;</tspan>
            <tspan class="service" dx="5px">radon</tspan>
          </text>

        </svg>
      </g>

      <!--  HOUSE DETECTIVES LLC  -->
      <g id="biz-name" transform="translate(265,140)scale(0.8)">
        <line x1="0" x2="500" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: green"></line>
        <text dx="70px" dy="0"
          text-anchor="start"
          font-size="38px"
          font-family="Roboto Slab"
          font-weight="bold"
          transform="rotate(-90)"
          class="logo">the</text>
        <text dx="0" dy="0"
          text-anchor="start"
          font-size="78px"
          font-family="Roboto Slab"
          font-weight="bold"
          class="logo">
            <tspan class="name" x="5" dx="0" dy="-73">House</tspan>
            <tspan class="name" x="-70" dx="0" dy="65">Detectives</tspan>
            <tspan class="name" x="0" dx="330" dy="-2" font-size="24px">llc</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Paul--notice that yours does not render properly. The rectangle with text along the bottom is cut off. I've played around with setting the `viewBox` programmatically with javascript, and the `viewBox` is (rounded) `"0 0 16 149"` which corresponds to the height of 165. I've edited the svg to a `viewBox` of `"0 0 1920 165"` but see no improvement.

Comment: Sorry. I got the viewBox a bit wrong. I have corrected it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help with opening in inkscape or converting with imagemagick. Same problem.

Comment: I was trying to help you get the SVG responsive so you don't have to convert it to a PNG.  The reason it won't convert to a PNG is for other reasons.  Those would include the fact that they almost certainly don't sipport the recent CSS features that you are using. Such as font imports and CSS params. Also `alignment-baseline` is probably not supported either.  If you really want a PNG, why not just load it in your browser and do a screenshot?

Comment: @Paul--I would like at least 1920px wide resolution. I didn't think a screenshot would give me that. But it turns out you are completely right. Actually, I have an FHD screen, and it came out 3690px wide! I'd prefer to have it SVG so I can easily play with colors, but at least this is a solution.

Comment: The problem I'm having isn't scaling the svg itself. It's controlling it using css in the web page. Because of the fonts, I need to put it in inline, as opposed to an img, object, or background. I can't seem to get any css width or height to actually do anything to it.

Comment: If you want to control it via CSS, then all you need to do is remove the `width` and `height` attributes from the top level `<svg>` element.